# PhalconPHP: I have an error in create model by devtools

Tags: command-line, model, phalcon, devtools

I'm using windows and my table name is "products"!

Command:

> phalcon create-model --table-name products

Error:

> Error: Unknow parameter 'table-name'

What is the problem?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be:

```
phalcon model --name products
```

Or:

```
phalcon model products
```

If you need to check what options are available in certain command, type:

```
phalcon model
```